# Troubles with if-statement ||

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, if-statement

I'm just working on a new porject an I'm working actually with simple coordinates:

```
if (locationOnJoystick.x > joystickArea.frame.size || locationOnJoystick.y > joystickArea.frame.size) {
```

But while running the code I get an ERROR:

> error: invalid operands to binary > (have 'CGFloat' and 'CGSize')

Can anyone see the solution?!

Sincerly,
mavrick3.

Comment: And now you've learned an important lesson → that the answer to your problem is in the description of the error. If it tells you there is a problem with CGFloats and CGSizes have a look at the CGFloats and the CGSizes in the code.

Comment: You're right. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`locationOnJoystick.x` is a `CGFloat`, while `joystickArea.frame.size` is a `CGSize`. They're different types, you cannot compare them.

I guess you should compare `locationOnJoystick.x` with the width of your `joystickArea.frame.size` (and the same with y and height):

```
if (locationOnJoystick.x > joystickArea.frame.size.width || locationOnJoystick.y > joystickArea.frame.size.height) {
```

Comment: Thank you :-) I'll accept your answer for your reputations as soon as possible.